# Terminal won't receive Control+← or Control+→

Tags: macos, terminal, keyboard

I just upgraded to Mountain Lion and I'm perplexed to find that neither iTerm 2 or the standard terminal will not receive <kbd>Control ⌃</kbd>+<kbd>←</kbd> or <kbd>⌃</kbd>+<kbd>→</kbd>, which I typically use to jump words on the command line. I can, however, use <kbd>⌃</kbd>+<kbd>↑</kbd> and <kbd>⌃</kbd>+<kbd>↓</kbd> which I'm finding odd.

I've tested this by opening up `cat` on stdin and mashing buttons. My initial guess is that OS X is intercepting them somehow, I suspected Spaces (I guess it's part of Mission Control now) at first, but after disabling all key combinations for it, I've come up empty-handed.

Has anyone ever seen this before, or does anyone have any other ideas?

Answer (score 2):

This is because <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>←</kbd> and <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>→</kbd> are bound to changing spaces in **Mission Control**.

[image: Keyboard Shortcuts]

Comment: The OP's question indicates that he's removed those shortcuts.

Answer (score 1):

<kbd>option</kbd><kbd>f</kbd> - Jump Forward a Word

<kbd>option</kbd><kbd>b</kbd> - Jump Back a Word

From the bash manpage:

> ```
>    forward-word (M-f)
>          Move forward to the end of the next word.  Words are composed of alphanumeric characters (letters and digits).
>   backward-word (M-b)
>          Move back to the start of the current or previous word.  Words are composed of alphanumeric characters (letters and digits).
> ```

If you open up Terminal.app (the OS X built-in terminal), open preferences, choose the 'Settings' section, and click 'Keyboard' in the navigation strip.

[image: Terminal Keyboard Preferences]

The shortcut is defined here. It may be possible to modify that, or I would suggest *duplicating* it, using `control cursor left` with the same `\033b` action, and `control cursor right` with `\033f`.

Comment: This doesn't help that the terminal won't respond to ^← or ^→. I know how to bind keys to actions, but I don't know why the terminal isn't responding to the keys being pressed.

Comment: I think you should file a [Radar](https://bugreport.apple.com/) that even when you disable the shortcut, something still traps it.

Comment: I can verify that Terminal will respond to Control-Left/Right if they aren't intercepted elsewhere. The default Terminal keyboard map even includes mappings for them, and they work if I turn off the Mission Control shortcuts.